# Is * a legal selector in CSS? If so, why does it generate this output when setting display to block?

Tags: html, css, language-lawyer

I though the following was something innocent

```css
* {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
hello
```

Comment: Because `*` matches **everything** including elements normally defaulted to `display:none;`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's just a StackOverflow thing.

Comment: @Rojo, the same can be reproduced on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: @Mgetz, so it's a bit like the snippet is not "insulated" from the external environment?

Comment: @Enlico so any element inside `<body>` will display if it's not `display:none;` in your example the tool adds a `<style>` element inside the body. You're then changing it's default style from `display:none;` to `display:block;` so that's dumping the contents visibly onto the page.

Comment: That's because JSFiddle and StackOverflow both show code similarly. If you use `* {}` in a personal .html file or on a localhost website, it will work perfectly fine.

Comment: This has nothing to do specifically with SO or jsfiddle. Any HTML which has that in the stylesheet will end up dumping the stylesheet(s) contents out. It just looks a bit weirder on SO because SO's way of dealing with a console has is styling dumped out too.